# JOIN on the latest record of another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two datasets
First one: Customers - Has the ID of every customer and it's attributes etc..
Second one: Comments - Has multiple comments for every customer

In the Comments table i also have the ID of the customer related to the comment, but every costumer may have multiple comments.

I want to join on the first table (Customers) the last comment that was made for them.

```
SELECT Customers.Name
FROM Customers LEFT JOIN
     Comments
     ON Customers.ID = (SELECT MAX(CommentID)
                        FROM Comments
                        WHERE Customers.ID = Comments.CustomerID
                       )
```

I'm using MAX(CommentID) to get the last comment that was added to the table.

However this throws me a syntax error, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is the syntax error?  What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get all the last comments for each customer and then join to the table:

```
SELECT cus.Name, com.*
FROM Customers AS cus LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM Comments
  WHERE CommentID IN (
    SELECT MAX(CommentID)
    FROM Comments
    GROUP BY CustomerID
  )
) AS com ON cus.ID = com.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you intend:

```
SELECT cu.Name, co.*
FROM Customers cu LEFT JOIN
     Comments co
     ON co.customerId = cu.ID AND
        co.ID = (SELECT MAX(co2.ID)
                 FROM Comments co2
                 WHERE co.CustomerID = co2.CustomerID
                );
```

In MS Access you probably have to write this as:

```
SELECT cu.Name, co.*
FROM Customers as cu LEFT JOIN
     Comments as co
     ON co.customerId = cu.ID AND
WHERE co.ID IS NULL OR
      co.ID = (SELECT MAX(co2.ID)
               FROM Comments as co2
               WHERE co.CustomerID = co2.CustomerID
              );
```

Although your query is not logically correct, I'm not sure why it would have a syntax error.  One possibility is that the `id`s in the two tables have incompatible types.  Or perhaps you are not naming the columns correctly in your query.

Comment: I tried that exactly and it doesn't work.
I'm running the querys on a MS Access Database.
i reviewed this query all my afternoon and can't get why it doesn't work.
Howeever, both the subquery and the Normal query with a random ID work pretty fine...